# struts tiles modifying dynamically

Tags: dynamic, struts2, tiles

I have a problem regarding tiles of struts2.x.
I have this video.jsp file which will always have it's address extended by `video.jsp?v=22/23/14(any number)`, but when I use tiles I can only call video.jsp as:

```
<definition name="video" template="/layout.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Video Page"></put-attribute>
<put-attribute name="header" value="/headerhome.jsp"></put-attribute>
<put-attribute name="body" value="/video.jsp"></put-attribute>
</definition>
```

So my question is how can I make it dynamic like `video.jsp?v=22(for example)` ?
I hope that this community helps me as it always did.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass a variable from struts2-action to JSP by exposing the getters of the property in the action and then that variable is easily available through valueStack in the JSP.

For e.g.
`<s:property value="var"/>` in JSP works if you have created getters for var field in the action.

In your current situation, you can simply have a variable named v in action and use that in JSP through valueStack.